# Google Video Intelligence operation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

I tried the demo at https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/

If I switch to the API tab I can see the request is

```
https://videointelligence.googleapis.com/v1/operations/projects/4808913407/locations/us-east1/operations/12700896084805575820?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
```

However, when I try doing the same operation using my API key I get

```
    {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Do I need to configure the API key in any specific way to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Video Intelligence does not support API Keys, you need to authenticate using a service account. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) you can find the list of GCP services that support API Keys.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/quickstart#quickstart-detect-labels-cli) you can find a description step-by-step on how to use video intelligence using the command line.

As you can see you need to generate a print access token after configuring your service account credentials. Then you include it in the API call as "Authorization: Bearer". You cannot use an API key.